# Unable to render a powerpoint documents using @cyntler/react-doc-viewer

Tags: reactjs

I'm using @cyntler/react-doc-viewer, and am able in a react JS app to render image files, and text files, but there is always an error when trying to render a .docx, .xlsx, or .pptx. It points to a Microsoft site to explain the error, but nothing shows up at that site to explain anything. Is there something that needs to be done so that these files can be rendered?